# WritersCanShare - google drive API

Tags: go, google-api

Im developing a software that will use google drive and google docs. Recently I discovered that there is an option in google drive sharing menu: prevent others from sharing a document. I wanted to implement this in my application using Go language, but with no lack.

The problem is, I do an Insert file call (using google drive api) with WritersCanShare field set to false, but still users with writer role can share a file. Here is the code block:

```
file, err = srv.Files.Insert(&drive.File{                    
            CreatedDate: time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339),        
            MimeType:    "application/vnd.google-apps.document", 
            Title:       "sometitle",
            WritersCanShare: false,                   
}).Do()
```

So, what can I do to solve the issue ?

I use service account to create files and give owner role to my main google account.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using a different account to test the 'writer role can share' feature? AFAIK, the account that creates a file has all the permissions on it.

Comment: @giulio-micheloni Yes, I have 2 test google accounts. First I create a file, give owner role to my main account, then writer role to my test account.

Comment: Is the file inserted in a shared folder? Moreover, have you tried with the CLI for Google Drive? Just to see if it is a bug of Go SDK.

Comment: @GiulioMicheloni file is inserted in root folder of service account (so not shared), I just give owner role to main account and writer role to test account. Didn't try CLI yet, btw you mean that one -> (https://github.com/gdrive-org/gdrive) ?

Comment: Correct. But you should be able to create the HTTP request manually and see if it works as expected. In case it does not, I would open an issue in Go SDK Github repo.

Comment: @GiulioMicheloni I tried to see response from server when I create a file and I saw that even though I set WritersCanShare field to false, in response it's set to true.